# Cache Handling with Moya

Tags: swift, alamofire, moya

We have implemented Moya, RxSwift And Alamofire as pods in our project.

Does anyone know how you gain control of the cache policies per url request using this tech?

I have read through quite a few of the issues on Moya's GitHub page but still can't find anything. Also tried using actual json response stored as files for the sampleData like so:

```
var sampleData: Data {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SampleAggregate", ofType: "txt") else {
        return "sampleData".utf8Encoded
    }
    let sample = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    return sample!.utf8Encoded

}
```

Thanks in advance for any pro tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `MoyaProvider` and compose `requestClosure`.

It should look something like:

```
final class MyProvider<Target: TargetType>: MoyaProvider<Target> {

    public init(
        endpointClosure: @escaping EndpointClosure = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping,
        requestClosure: @escaping RequestClosure = MoyaProvider.defaultRequestMapping,
        stubClosure: @escaping StubClosure = MoyaProvider.neverStub,
        manager: Manager = MoyaProvider<Target>.defaultAlamofireManager(),
        plugins: [PluginType] = [],
        trackInflights: Bool = false
    ) {
        super.init(
            endpointClosure: endpointClosure,
            requestClosure: { endpoint, closure in
                var request = try! endpoint.urlRequest() //Feel free to embed proper error handling
                if request.url == URL(string: "http://google.com")! {
                    request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad
                } else {
                    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                }
                closure(.success(request))
            },
            stubClosure: stubClosure,
            manager: manager,
            plugins: plugins,
            trackInflights: trackInflights
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 26):

As to my understanding, the "cleanest" way to solve this, is to use a custom Moya Plugin. Here's an implementation:

```
protocol CachePolicyGettable {
    var cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy { get }
}  

final class CachePolicyPlugin: PluginType {
    public func prepare(_ request: URLRequest, target: TargetType) -> URLRequest {
        if let cachePolicyGettable = target as? CachePolicyGettable {
            var mutableRequest = request
            mutableRequest.cachePolicy = cachePolicyGettable.cachePolicy
            return mutableRequest
        }

        return request
    }
}
```

To actually use this plugin, there are two required steps left:

1. The plugin should be added to your Moya provider like this:

   ```
   let moyaProvider = MoyaProvider<YourMoyaTarget>(plugins: [CachePolicyPlugin()])
   ```
2. `YourMoyaTarget`should conform to `CachePolicyGettable` and thereby define the cache policy for each target:

   ```
   extension YourMoyaTarget: CachePolicyGettable {
       var cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy {
           switch self {
           case .sampleTarget, .someOtherSampleTarget:
               return .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

           default:
               return .useProtocolCachePolicy
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:** This approach uses a protocol to associate cache policies with target types; one could also realise this via a closure being passed to the plugin. Such closure would then decide which cache policy to use depending on the target type passed as an input parameter to the closure.

Comment: Really good answer. I just wanted to know For how long the response will get saved.

Comment: The actual caching is handled via the underlying URLRequest - so to understand what it’s doing, you will have to do some research there

Answer (score 3):

Based on @fredpi answer, I slightly improved caching plugin for Moya. Below is my version:

```swift
import Foundation
import Moya

protocol CachePolicyGettable {
    var cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy { get }
}

final class NetworkDataCachingPlugin: PluginType {

    init (configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, inMemoryCapacity: Int, diskCapacity: Int, diskPath: String?) {
        configuration.urlCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: inMemoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: diskPath)
    }

    func prepare(_ request: URLRequest, target: TargetType) -> URLRequest {
        if let cacheableTarget = target as? CachePolicyGettable {
            var mutableRequest = request
            mutableRequest.cachePolicy = cacheableTarget.cachePolicy
            return mutableRequest
        }
        return request
    }
}

extension NetworkApiService: CachePolicyGettable {
    var cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy {
        switch self {
        case .getUserProfile:
            return .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        default:
            return .useProtocolCachePolicy
        }
    }
}
```

In order to clear the cache, you need to have an access to urlRequest object/objects. How to retrieve an urlRequest for Moya route you can find in the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259898/1994889) topic.

To clear the cache you can use following code:

```
public func clearCache(urlRequests: [URLRequest] = []) {
    let provider = ... // your Moya provider
    guard let urlCache = provider.manager.session.configuration.urlCache else { return }
    if urlRequests.isEmpty {
        urlCache.removeAllCachedResponses()
    } else {
        urlRequests.forEach { urlCache.removeCachedResponse(for: $0) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the stored cookies as well

```
request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
```