# How to retry request using Moya framework

Tags: swift, moya

I am trying to integrate Moya which found to be a good framework in designing a network layer. I am stuck in how to retry a network request. Is it possible to get a request variable from Moya provider when we receive an error? Please note, I am looking for an answer in swift not Rxswift

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. According latest Moya API, there's no way to retrieve network task to be call it again if it fails.
 It only returns `Cancellable` type, which allows you check whether task is executing - `isCancelled`, or to `cancel()` request.
If you need just urlRequest object, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259898/1994889) answer for the details. But if you really need to implement "retry" functionality, you have to store `route` variable and completion closure at your intermediate Moya wrapper and call re-run it when needed.